# How to use the result "as" in "where" without using the second nested query

Tags: mysql

There is such a table

```
CREATE TABLE line (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Command varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO line (id,Command) values(1,'A');
INSERT INTO line (id,Command) values(2,'B');
INSERT INTO line (id,Command) values(3,'C');
INSERT INTO line (id,Command) values(4,'D');
INSERT INTO line (id,Command) values(5,'A');
```

I want to refer to the alias in the condition.

```
SELECT (SELECT `id` FROM `line` WHERE `command` = 'A') as `a` FROM `line` WHERE `a` != 5
```

How can I do this without one more query in it?

Comment: Can you please show the result you expected?

Comment: first line in insert into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

You do have to physically repeat the subquery but it doesn't get executed a second time.

The server executes the subquery when evaluating `WHERE`, and the `SELECT` reuses that result when returning the row.  The optimizer recognizes that the value is equivalent.

Many people overlook the fact that `SELECT` is written first, but does not happen first. `WHERE` happens earlier.  `SELECT` returns the data that `WHERE` has determined should be included (or should not be excluded).

Conceptually, the operations occur differently than they way they are expressed in a query... it happens in an order more like this:

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
```

So, technically, if one of the appearances of the subquery is redundant... then, technically, the redundant appearance is actually the one in `SELECT`, not the one in `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use an alias in where clause.

Try to use join

```
SELECT t1.id FROM `line` t1 join line t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t2.`command`='A' and t2.id!=5
```

See the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca9b3/9) also. And rename column command, it is a keyword.

Comment: Try to fulfill your request on my table

Comment: Yes, an interesting decision to associate with itself

Answer (score 0):

The use of alias inside the where condition is not allowed  in mysql but your result could be obtained  using a not in

```
select id FROM line 
where id   not in (  
      SELECT id 
      FROM line 
      WHERE command = 'A' 
      and id =5)
```

or  using an inner join

```
select id  FROM line as t1 where id 
inner join  ( 
  SELECT id 
  FROM line 
  WHERE command = 'A' 
  and id =5
)  a on t1.id <> a.id
```

and also creating a view

Comment: I spoke without the nested request in the conditions

Comment: i don't understand your comment  please explain better  ..  anyway if the problem is != 5 i have update the asnwer

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM line as t1 where id 
inner join  ( 
  SELECT id 
  FROM line 
  WHERE c' at line 1